# Android Java: how to pass values from activity on running onto notifications bar

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, notifications

I have developed a program whereby it allows user to review the decibel reading of the song they are playing at. The reading is always being updated using the onRunning method. I want to make a notification for my application such that when the user exits the application, the status bar still runs, and the always-changing value is on the status bar. Is that possible? And what is the overview solution flow? I have not touched services before so I just need a overview flow before I dive in. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a lot of good information from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html).

also i think you want to look into **Ongoing notifications**

Ongoing notifications keep users informed about an ongoing process in the background. For example, music players announce the currently playing track in the notification system and continue to do so until the user stops the playback. They can also be used to show the user feedback for longer tasks like downloading a file, or encoding a video. Ongoing notifications cannot be manually removed from the notification drawer.
Have fun.

EDIT :

**Is that possible?**  - Yes.

**And what is the overview solution flow?**

After you set up your notification you can use

`public void notify (int id, Notification notification)`

Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

Parameters

id - An identifier for this notification unique within your application.

notification - A Notification object describing what to show the user. Must not be null.

Answer (score 0):

That's right. You need to create a background service that will continue to run even after all the activities have terminated. The service should have a thread that periodically reads the decibels and updates the notification.

To create such service you should make sure that you use the `START_STICKY` flag or alternatively, start it as a separate process. The notification should be created by the service (and not by an activity) and updated by a the thread you spawned in the service.

You should also have code to remove the notification when the service terminates, otherwise it might continue to show up even though you're not reading decibels anymore.